# After Magento ver. 1.9.1.1 upgrade to Magento ver. 1.9.3.8 I am not able to access "system" -> configuration -> design tab

Tags: magento, upgrade

I have upgraded Magento ver. 1.9.1.1 to Magento ver. 1.9.3.8 .

After that most of things works fine but I am not able to access system -> configuration -> Design tab.

It give:

( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray' not found in C:\wamp64\sites\example.com\app\Mage.php on line 549

Also this  error is also coming to Mailchimp and Sweet Monkey option under MageMonkey extension option.

Please can any one can tell me why its coming and why other filed are working fine and how this can be resolved as I think there is any file missing on code missing in any file.

check error image

[image]

Comment: First things first. Was the upgrade script run without any error? Did you empty the cache, log out and the log in after the upgrade?

Comment: Before upgrade, Yes I have cleared cache, and then start upgrade from connect manager by "Mage_All_Latest" option and done login log out many time.

Comment: Have you check UnserializeArray.php file is exist in the right place?, please check and verify the file contents with any fresh v1.9.3.8 installation. Maybe it got corrupted or deleted accidentally while upgrading.

Comment: Yes, Rehan Mobin.
This is UnserializeArray.php file that was missing after upgrade in path
" app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper "

It was not created as this files is not present in my old magento version 1.9.1.1 
Now I have added this file manually from latest version(v 1.9.3.8) and system -> configuration -> Design tab is is working fine.
Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try following upgrade process: 
Make full backup via your favorite backup tool :)

Then use following SSH commands to run the upgrade process:
    cd ~/public
    chmod 750 mage
    ./mage config-set preferred_state stable
    ./mage list-upgrades
    ./mage upgrade-all --force

Once the update is completed, we should use this command to make database upgrade:

```
php -f ./index.php
```

Change back file permissions:

```
grep -rZl ‘0660’ . | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e ‘s/0660/0644/g’
grep -rZl ‘0770’ . | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e ‘s/0770/0755/g’
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Make sure to clean your cache:

```
rm -rf var/cache
```